# 404 not found on Laravel API routes using nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I am trying to set up a server with `PHP 7.2` and `nginx`. I can get the laravel homepage to load when I navigate to `my-site.com/snow` however I can't get any of the API routes defined in `API.php` to load. All of my API routes are prefixed with `/api/` like `/api/login`. I get a `404` error on all my API routes. What am I doing wrong?

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
  # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
  # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

location /snow {
  index index.php;
}

location /snow/api {
  root /var/www/html/snow;
  rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ snow/api/.+\.php$ {
  root /var/www/html/snow;
  rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
  #include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
```

.htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

<Files .env>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 9):

i had the same issue

i replaced

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

with

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `api.php` routes file, Laravel already prefixes those routes with `/api`, so you may be duplicating that in your config. Check if `/api/api/login` works.

If the above works, you don't need the two `/api` rules in your nginx config. Once you remove those rules, you should be able to access the APIs using `/api/login`.

You can also try updating your nginx config to the following, as your current config doesn't appear to be pointing to the public directory of Laravel:

```
location /snow/api {
  root /var/www/html/snow/pubic;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```